# Symfony2 + Doctrine2 / building a form from 2 joined entity objects

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to build a form from 2 joined entity objects?

I have two entities `property` & `propertylanguage` which are joined on onetomany relation.
(One property can have many languages)

Language has a `title` and `description` colomns.
So one property can have a english, french, german title.

I am trying to build a form out of that.
See below.

**Controller:** addProperty.php

```
class AddPropertyController extends Controller
{
    // ....

    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $property = new  property;
        $language = new  propertyLanguage;
        $property ->addpropertylanguage($language);

        $form = $this->createForm(new propertyType($this->getDoctrine()),$property);

       // ..... 

    }
```

**Form type**: propertType.php

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add('title', 'text');
           // other ->add() below.

    }
```

It returns the following error:

> Neither property "title" nor method "getTitle()" nor method
>   "isTitle()" exists in class "\defaultBundle\Entity\property"

Of course there is no property Title in property, but there is one in propertylanguage..
Even if I try:
->add('title', 'entity', array('class'=>defaultBundle:propertylanguage));
it doesn't work.

Thanks if you have time to help me.

Best,

Pierre.

Answer (score 1):

What you will want to do is make a PropertyLanguageType class as well as a PropertyType.

Then, in your PropertyType you will embed the PropertyLanguageType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{

    // $builder->add('propertyLanguage', new PropertyLanguageType());

    // Since we have a 1 to many relation, then a collection is needed
    $builder->add('propertyLanguage', 'collection', array('type' => new PropertyLanguageType()));
```

The PropertyLanguageType is where you add the title.

It's all in the forms section in the manual but it might take several readings.

A second approach is to add a getTitle to your Property entity which would return the title from the PropertyLanguage entity.  By doing this, your original form will work.  But it can be a bit of a mess when you start to have multiple associations with multiple attributes.  Best to just define a type for each entity.

Comment: Hi Cerad, Thanks a lot, you give me what I needed. It works perfect!
I am still under 15 reputations so I cannot vote for your response.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks though it seems like you should be able to accept the answer?  In any event, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a query_builder when defining the form. Here's how your form class might look like. Of course it will certainly not be exactly as so but that will give you a good start ;)

```
public function __construct($id)
{
    $this->propertylanguageId = $id;
}   

public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('propertylanguage', 'entity', array(
                    'label' => 'Property Language',
                    'class' => 'YourAdressToBundle:Propertylanguage',
                    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($propertylanguageId) {
                                            return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
                                            ->join('p.property', 'prop', Expr\Join::WITH, 'prop.id = :propertylanguageId')
                                            ->setParameter('propertylanguageId', $propertylanguageId);
                                       },
                ));
}
```

Hope that'll be helpful

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your time and help.
Actually I prefer to avoid queryBuilder because I don't think it works if I want to build the form from entities object.
In instance: $form = $this->createForm(new propertyType($this->getDoctrine()),$property);

I'll go wz Cerad answer which looks more best practice.
Thanks again for your time

Comment: Hi, well I used it myself once for a project and it does work but Cerad solution certainly works as well! Happy coding ;)